# How to call Shell script or python script in from a Atom electron app

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, shell, electron

I'm trying to use the Atom electron to write a Desktop App for both Mac and Windows.

What I need here is :

A button.

And when the user click the button it runs the following shell (or python script):

```
ping x.x.x.x
```

And the result will be displayed in a TextArea.

I tried to use [shelljs] and [yargs] but it seems like it is not workable with Atom electron.

All I want is to use JAVASCRIPT to write Desktop App (with GUI of course) that calls some script (shell && python) to do some automation work.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 33):

It can be done directly with Node, you can use the `child_process` module. Please notice this is asynchronous.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function execute(command, callback) {
    exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => { 
        callback(stdout); 
    });
};

// call the function
execute('ping -c 4 0.0.0.0', (output) => {
    console.log(output);
});
```

I encourage you to also have a look at [npm](http://npmjs.com), there are tons of modules that could help you to do what you want, without calling a python script.

Comment: I'm using electron and I get `runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?9e79:217 Uncaught TypeError: exec is not a function` when

Answer (score 5):

Try **node-powershell** npm. You can directly execute shell script commands and display result.

```
var shell = require('node-powershell')
var ps = new shell()
ps.addCommand('ping -c 4 0.0.0.0')
ps.invoke()
.then(function (output) {
    console.log(output)
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
    ps.dispose()
})
```

**See:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell

Answer (score 4):

you could use child_process to archive what you are trying to do by using the following code

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
function Callback(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(`exec error: ${err}`);
        return;
    }else{
        console.log(`${stdout}`);
    }
}

res = exec('ping xxx.xxx.xxx', Callback);
```