# Execute R script using Electron and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, r, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am creating an Electron desktop application using ReactJS and MaterialUI how do I execute an R script after a user clicks a button?  I currently have this react code:

```
 handleClickOpen(event) {
       //what goes here?
 } 

<Button fab mini color="primary" aria-label="add" className={this.props.button} onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>
<AddIcon />
</Button>
```

Comment: Sure, [*shell out*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079548/how-to-call-shell-script-or-python-script-in-from-a-atom-electron-app) and [*run it*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line).

Answer (score 0):

Try rquery package in npm. It may give you an idea for the possibility of R and React js.