# I am trying to use a locally hosted Django webserver's HTML button to execute a python script that's on my local machine and I'm stumped

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

So, I'm pretty new to Django, python, and javascript.

I have a partially functional Django webserver that, while developing it, I host locally on my machine.

I've made a button with HTML which I've figured out can be tied to a javascript script. The next step for me was to make this button "execute" a python script that's sitting on my machine, particularly on the /desktop directory. I can of course move the script though, but the important part is that I want that python script (let's call it django_test_script.py) to open its own window on my machine. It's just a file that says "hi" in stdout, then closes after 5 seconds, but due to the plan for this whole project, I want that to happen. I want to have my website open on my machine, click that button, then have the script's console pop up on my desktop and run/finish.

The eventual goal is to control an LED strip that's plugged into my raspberry pi. I want colored buttons on the website that, when clicked, run appropriate python scripts that turn the lights to that color. It wouldn't take me long to write up the python scripts themselves that would change colors, but I need to bridge the gap between "button causes a py script to run" and the python script actually running.

I see a ton of questions similar to this, but they all seem to involve running the python scripts WITHIN the webserver, like internal files that do everything and then return something to the server via an HttpResponse.

I don't need an HttpResponse. Literally all I want to do for right now is figure out how to make a script that's stored on the machine run.

I've done some reading on AJAX and I'm guessing that's involved, however everything I've tried has failed with AJAX in terms of actually getting the server to RUN a script. I've been scouring the internet for over an hour now and have found basically nothing useful (as far as I can tell) so I figured I may as well ask for help. Can someone please point me in the right direction in terms of what I'll need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not possible. The browser doesn't allow to execute local scripts since everything is (for security reasons) in a sandbox.
If you want to execute something you could do one of the following:

- Use a http server which executes the script and call it via AJAX
- You build it into an exectron / nodejs app which opens more possibilities to access the system. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079548/how-to-call-shell-script-or-python-script-in-from-a-atom-electron-app)

But from your requirement I assume the website will be opened on another device to remote control the Pi led? If you you'll need to use some sort of http server as otherwise you can't run the script on the pi itself.

Comment: Thank you for responding to me! I really appreciate it. 

How, then, do people commonly do things like control their devices remotely over a network? For example, I've seen loads of examples where people load into simple webpages on their main computer, hit something, and their arduino does something across the room. How are those kinds of connections typically made if not the way I'm imagining? 

Also, yes, your assumption was correct. Plan is to host the webserver on the pi to the local network and control the pi from that webpage with other devices.

Comment: I understand that SSH connections are used to control over CLI, which is what I currently do, but I'd like to do that controlling of scripts over the network via a webpage. It's definitely looking like I'll need to do an http server of some kind, and execute the script with AJAX, but like I said, I'm finding basically nothing on how to actually do that without massively complicated extra stuff that don't apply to my use case, but I also don't know what fluff I need to remove from those examples. If that makes sense.

Comment: They work exactly as described: The arduino runs a (very) small http server which serves the web page (which will be opened from the other pc) as well as handling incoming rest requests which execute a certain action (e.g. turn a pin on).
An example can be found here: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/arduino-webserver-with-an-arduino-ethernet-shield/

Comment: It's important to note that when using ajax you should host the page at the same IP/domain. Otherwise your browser will block the request and you'll need to enable XSS